# Dynamically getting/setting a property of an object in C# 2005

Tags: c#, reflection

I've inherited a code base and I'm writing a little tool to update a database for it.  The code uses a data access layer like SubSonic (but it is home-grown).  There are many properties of an object, like "id", "templateFROM" and "templateTO", but there are 50 of them.

On screen, I can't display all 50 properties each in their own textbox for data entry, so I have a listbox of all the possible properties, and one textbox for editing.  When they choose a property in the listbox, I fill the textbox with the value that property corresponds to.  Then I need to update the property after they are done editing.

Right now I'm using 2 huge switch case statements.  This seems stupid to me.  Is there a way to dynamically tell C# what property I want to set or get?  Maybe like:

```
entObj."templateFROM" = _sVal;
```

??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use System.Reflection for that task.

```
entObj.GetType().GetProperty("templateFROM").SetValue(entObj, _sVal, null);
```

This should help you.

Comment: Yeah, there's NO WAY I would have guessed that syntax.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

What you want is called [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is Reflection.  Here's a little snippet:

```
Type t = entObj.GetType();
t.GetProperty("templateFROM").SetValue(entObj, "new value", null);
```

On more of a usability note (and less of an answering-your-question note), you might want to look into using a [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx) control.  That listbox/textbox sounds like it could be pretty tedious to use.

Comment: Excellent suggestion on the PropertyGrid control -- however, the stuff we are editing is multiline, and may not quite work very well.  But you are right, this will get tedious.  Hopefully I'll get a brainflash.  Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(YourClass).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
```

you can bind this to your drop down list, and later on:

```
PropertyInfo property = typeof(YourClass).GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
property.SetValue(class, textBox.Text, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

On a related note, you're users will *hate* this interface if they need to update a lot of properties at once.  Can you divide the properties into groups or pages that the user can move through more quickly?

Comment: I agree, they will hate it.  However, we are trying to get a quick and dirty demo out the door.  We have about 30 of these fields, always the same fields, and they are all fields where the user will enter a pattern (including carriage returns, hence multiline) to match on.

Comment: A scrollable grid would also work.  Then it could still be data driven, allow multi-line input, and not require your users to do as much navigation.

Answer (score 0):

This sample is helpful

```
public class aa
{
    private string myVar;

    public string value
    {
        get { return myVar; }
        set { myVar = value; }
    }   
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    aa a1 = new aa();
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pt = typeof(aa).GetProperty("value");
    pt.SetValue(a1, "hi",null);
    this.Text = a1.value;
}
```